# In C++, are custom header files optional?

Tags: c++, c, header

This was asked on a past exam. Given that the header file is custom I am assuming not because they are just variations of the main(){ header correct?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  In both C and C++ you can have header files that don't(and shouldn't) have a main() function.

Comment: what is it that you want to ask exactly? be more precise and use more words , if possible give a history of the  problem

Comment: Why is the question tagged "C" but the title says "C++"? Is this acutally a Java question?

Comment: It was a true or false. We are using C programming in the class. It said in C++ custom header files optional, True or False.

Comment: If the question is "Is it possible to write a valid C or C++ program that doesn't use any `#include` directives", then the answer is "yes": `int main() {}` is such a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I would say yes, they are optional. You could write all of your (custom) functions, classes, etc. in one file if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here so I can't comment, but the question is a bit confusing to me. But here is what I think, I hope it helps:

Header files contain functions, variables, classes etc. in C and C++. Header files that come pre-built with your compiler must be included before you can use any function or anything thing inside that file.

Now referring to a custom header files, you may choose to create a file containing specific information to use in your programs, often to make your code look more organize or to create reusable libraries. Those are OPTIONAL simply because you can manage to create all your functions, variables and classes in the same file containing your main(){}. It might look messy, impossible to read but possible to achieve.

BTW I'm not sure about what you mean by header files being variations of the main(), but agreeing with Trevor Hickey, they shouldn't have a main() function since they are not compilable, they don't execute the functions they just hold the information.